Вопрос касаемо создания кнопок и раздвижного списка через Вебхук
Приветствую всех пользователей данного форума!
Столкнулся с таким вопросом. На многих серверах на которых я был и сижу до сих пор наблюдаю такую вещь, администраторы серверов как-то делают раздвижные списки и кнопки для выдачи роли, или просмотра определенных пунктов правил Discord сервера.
Если кто-то знает как их делать через WebHook, просьба подсказать, так как хочу чтобы у меня на сервере все правила и разделы были компактными и более удобными.
Также вставляю пару примеров с тех серверов на которых я видел данные списки и кнопки.


Заранее спасибо за помощь!❤️
